# Why is using a variable in if statement faster than a magic number?

Tags: python

Looking at some Leetcode questions, saw the solution below for reversing an integer

```
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    maxint = 2147483649
    minint = -2147483648
    ans = int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
    return ans * (abs(x)//x) if minint < ans < maxint and ans else 0
```

Thought that I could trivially improve the speed by replacing the variables `minint` and `maxint` with the values.

```
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    ans = int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
    return ans * (abs(x)//x) if -2147483648 < ans < 2147483649 and ans else 0
```

(the question is a little weird in that it asks to assume there are only 32 bits allocated to an integer, which should be error handled instead of this weird "check" after the fact?)

The second code block runs the tests in 40ms while the first runs in 28.

Why is it faster to use variables for the if instead of the values?

Comment: How many times did you actually run that test?

Comment: fair, I'm just trusting that leetcode does a decent job of estimating performance given how much they emphasize speed. Looking at an answer posted, that was actually the problem.

Comment: Leetcode actually does really bad on this estimating. Re-submit your answer mostly can get a better result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `timeit` for proper performance test. Your version is just slightly (although within error bar) faster as expected:

```
def f(x: int) -> int:
    maxint = 2147483649
    minint = -2147483648
    ans = int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
    return ans * (abs(x)//x) if minint < ans < maxint and ans else 0

def g(x: int) -> int:
    ans = int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
    return ans * (abs(x)//x) if -2147483648 < ans < 2147483649 and ans else 0

%timeit f(123456789)
#710 ns ± 16.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit g(123456789)
#700 ns ± 8.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Note that this "optimization" is quite irrelevant, especially since it also arguably reduces code readability...